# How to pause animations with kivy

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I'm using **kivy** to develop a small project. Currently, I use the animation utility to animate Widgets (change position, cycle through a sprite atlas, etc.). Everything works great so far, but I have no idea how I am supposed to pause animations and continue them at a later point. I know that I could use the Clock schedule mechanism and `clock.cancel`, but that would make the whole ànimation` class pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The Animation class has `start`, `stop` and `cancel` methods you can use to manipulate it how you like. Perhaps we should have a `pause` too, but you can achieve the same effect with those.

Comment: I thought in that direction, do you have any examples? I'm a bit afraid to start bookkeeping of all my animations. I would rather iterate all my widgets and call something like  "[for ani in my_widget.<???> ani.cancel]".

Comment: Examples of what? The documentation tells you how to use these things. Also remember that you don't have to really do extra bookkeeping: any abstraction you thought Kivy might have to help with this is also something you can build yourself.

Comment: I will note, that calling `stop` on an Animation will call the `on_complete` function, which, if you're using that, would make it tricky to pause an animation mid-frame and then re-start it from there. Now that I'm looking at how to do that, I agree that adding a `pause` method would be really nice.